# get and set value of object in List in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have a list of `objects`, and I need to search if a value exists in the list, if it does, I need to set one of the properties of the `object` found to another value, is it possible to do this without searching the `List` twice? (Once to check if the `object` exists in the list and once to set its value)

For example:

```
class myObject
{
   public string FieldNumber {get;set;}
   public string FieldValue  {get;set;}
}

var myValues = new List<myObject>();
myValues.Add(new myObject{ FieldNumber = "100A"});
myValues.Add(new myObject{ FieldNumber = "100B"});

var allValues = new List<myObject>();
allValues.Add(new myObject{ FieldNumber = "200A", FieldValue = "3"});
allValues.Add(new myObject{ FieldNumber = "100B", FieldValue = "C"});

foreach(var obj in allValues)
{
    GetAndSetField(myValues, obj.FieldNumber, obj.FieldValue);
}

void GetAndSetField(List<myObject> list, string fieldNumber, string fieldValue)
{
    var tempField = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FieldNumber.Equals(fieldNumber));
    if(tempField != null)
        list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FieldNumber.Equals(fieldNumber)).FieldValue = fieldValue;
}
```

Is it possible to change the code in the `GetAndSetField` method so that it doesn't search the list twice if the `object` is found? 
Or maybe I'm doing this completely wrong and there's an easier way...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're already reading out `tempField`. Just use it:

```
void GetAndSetField(List<myObject> list, string fieldNumber, string fieldValue)
{
    var tempField = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FieldNumber.Equals(fieldNumber));
    if (tempField != null)
        tempField.FieldValue = fieldValue;
}
```

Comment: I really thought that would work, I had tried it already, maybe my problem lies somewhere else. At least I know that it should work. Thanks

Comment: Is myObject really a `struct` instead of a `class`?

Comment: Then this should work fine. You can verify by reading it out of your list again and seeing that the `FieldValue` property is set correctly.

Comment: Oh, I see what's wrong. You're passing the wrong list into `GetAndSetField`. You should be passing `myValues`, not `allValues`.

Comment: actually that was a copying/pasting mistake, I was thinking your answer should work, I just wanted to make sure since it wasn't working correctly. I found out that the problem was that `fieldValue` was null so that's why it wasn't working.